# How can a logger with a parent logger have an effectiveLevel of 0?

Tags: python, logging

Playing around with logging inheritance, and slightly confused by the effective log levels I am seeing.

My file structure is as follows:

```
project/
--> __init.py__
--> some_folder/
----> some_file.py
```

In `__init.py__` I create the root logger from a dict config in a yaml file. I log its effectiveLevel and it is as expected(set to INFO in the yaml file). However, I log the effectiveLevel of the logger in some_file.py, and that comes out to 0. I realize the non-root loggers default to level NOTSET(0), but I would expect the effectiveLevel to be the same as the root logger, so INFO as opposed to 0.

Any idea why that is?

EDIT added code that creates logger:

yaml:

```
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: False
  formatters:
      simple:
      format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

  handlers:
      console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      stream: ext://sys.stdout

  root:
      level: INFO
      handlers: [console]
      propagate: no
```

inflation of config:

```
with open('path_to_yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Comment: Can you share the code that creates the `logger` objects?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was wrongly assuming that it would inherit the level of `root`. It looks like I needed to add a logger that was named as the project to accomplish the expected behavior.

```
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: False
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      stream: ext://sys.stdout

  loggers:
    project:
      level: INFO
      handlers: [console]
      propagate: no

  root:
      level: INFO
      handlers: [console]
```